# Unity GUI : splitting vertical layout group by ratio

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

In the picture above, I would like to fix the ratio of 'a' and 'b. 'A' is a 2, 'b' is definitively 1. What should I do?

Comment: Unity is *incredibly good* at reactive layout, but, don't expect to master it in just a couple weeks - it is an excellent and significant system. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this is precisely what the **VerticalLayoutGroup** is for.  (You also have HorizontalLayoutGroup for the other direction.)

First. Make a panel which will hold your two things.  Give it a **yellow** background so you can see it clearly. This will be your "holder".

Completely delete your red/blue things. Make sure the yellow holder is **exactly** the overall size you want it to be. Make sure you test that, with, the screen changing shape.  No matter what condition the screen is in and no matter what aspect ratio the screen is, your yellow holder should be perfect

Next, put a `VerticalLayoutGroup` on the yellow holder.

[image]

Then actually on ***EACH OF YOUR THINGS*** (there are two of them in your case), put a `LayoutElement`

[image]

Next you must set the `PreferredHeight` of your two things. (Where it shows "35" in that example image.)

In your case, choose two numbers such as say

## 200

## 100

for the PreferredHeight for your red and blue items.

Experiment with different values and you will see it change in the editor in realtime.

A full tutorial on using Unity's reactive layout system is beyond the scope of a QA page. The above will get you started.

Unity's reactive layout system for `.UI` is excellent. IMO it's better than Apple's system (Apple's "constraints" system), for example.